# Split file in context menu with powershell

Tags: powershell, function, split, contextmenu

I found the following code that allows to split files using Powershell: [Splitting Large Files in Smaller Parts (Part 1)](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/splitting-large-files-in-smaller-parts-part-1)

```
function Split-File
{
    
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]
        $Path,

        [Int32]
        $PartSizeBytes = 1MB
    )

    try
    {
        # get the path parts to construct the individual part
        # file names:
        $fullBaseName = [IO.Path]::GetFileName($Path)
        $baseName = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($Path)
        $parentFolder = [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($Path)
        $extension = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($Path)

        # get the original file size and calculate the
        # number of required parts:
        $originalFile = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo($Path)
        $totalChunks = [int]($originalFile.Length / $PartSizeBytes) + 1
        $digitCount = [int][Math]::Log10($totalChunks) + 1

        # read the original file and split into chunks:
        $reader = [IO.File]::OpenRead($Path)
        $count = 0
        $buffer = New-Object Byte[] $PartSizeBytes
        $moreData = $true

        # read chunks until there is no more data
        while($moreData)
        {
            # read a chunk
            $bytesRead = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
            # create the filename for the chunk file
            $chunkFileName = "$parentFolder\$fullBaseName.{0:D$digitCount}.part" -f $count
            Write-Verbose "saving to $chunkFileName..."
            $output = $buffer

            # did we read less than the expected bytes?
            if ($bytesRead -ne $buffer.Length)
            {
                # yes, so there is no more data
                $moreData = $false
                # shrink the output array to the number of bytes
                # actually read:
                $output = New-Object Byte[] $bytesRead
                [Array]::Copy($buffer, $output, $bytesRead)
            }
            # save the read bytes in a new part file
            [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($chunkFileName, $output)
            # increment the part counter
            ++$count
        }
        # done, close reader
        $reader.Close()
    }
    catch
    {
        throw "Unable to split file ${Path}: $_"
    }
}
```

I rewrote the code in one line and run it successfully at Powershell ISE. I want to put this code in the context menu to make it easier to work, it's like this:

```
powershell -noexit function Split-File{param([Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$Path,[Int32]$PartSizeBytes = 1MB);try{$fullBaseName = [IO.Path]::GetFileName($Path);$baseName = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($Path);$parentFolder =[IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($Path);$extension = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($Path);$originalFile = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo($Path);$totalChunks = [int]($originalFile.Length / $PartSizeBytes) + 1;$digitCount = [int][Math]::Log10($totalChunks) + 1;$reader = [IO.File]::OpenRead($Path);$count = 0;$buffer = New-Object Byte[] $PartSizeBytes;$moreData = $true;while($moreData){$bytesRead = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length);$chunkFileName = "$parentFolder\$fullBaseName.{0:D$digitCount}.part" -f $count;Write-Verbose "saving to $chunkFileName...";$output = $buffer;if ($bytesRead -ne $buffer.Length) {$moreData = $false;$output = New-Object Byte[] $bytesRead;[Array]::Copy($buffer, $output, $bytesRead)} [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($chunkFileName, $output);++$count};$reader.Close()}catch{throw "Unable to split file ${Path}: $_"}};Split-File -literalpath '%1'
```

However it didn't work, when right clicking on a file and selecting Split, I got the error message:

[image]

Pardon my ignorance, please tell me where I went wrong. Thanks very much.

Comment: Does changing this line `$chunkFileName = "$parentFolder\$fullBaseName.{0:D$digitCount}.part" -f $count` to this `$chunkFileName = "$parentFolder\{0}.{1:D$digitCount}.part" -f $fullBaseName, $count` help?

Comment: powershell.exe can call a file instead of a command. is there a reason not to do that? the pseudo one-liner idea is OK, but it is also very difficult to debug.

Comment: @codaamok Thank you for the guide, I followed it but it still doesn't work. I got the message: At line:1 char:673
+ ... d($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length);$chunkFileName = $parentFolder\{0}.{1:D ...
Unexpected token '\' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Read the suggestion in @codaamok s comment again. It clearly has quotes around the string to format, where you left these out

Comment: @Theo Thank you. But I didn't omit the quotes because I copied it from codaamok s comment. Error message omitted quotes (this also happens with the original code).

Comment: Rty `$chunkFileName = Join-Path -Path $parentFolder -ChildPath ("{0}.{1:D$digitCount}.part" -f $fullBaseName, $count)`

Comment: @Theo Thank you, I will learn more about this.